# Ajuda python pegando apenas o ultimo dado da lista

Tags: python, arquivo

Tenho um site e preciso de um sistema de separação de nome:sobrenome com lista, 
os dados ficam em um txt e eu importo normalmente os dados ficam por exemplo:
maria:carla
joao:lima
queria conseguir separar da seguinte forma quando desse print em dados ele deixaria em listas diferentes já que os dadoes estão cada um em uma linha ['maria','carla'] e ['joao,'lima'], e tambem separalo da seguinte forma por variaveis, nome = nomes[0]  sobrenome = nomes[1], quando desse um print em nome mostraria ['joao'] ['maria'],a primeira parte do codigo no momento ta assim, ele só está separando o primero nome:sobrenome da lista também gostaria de resolver isso:

```
    arquivo=raw_input("Digite o nome do arquivo para separar: ")
    ler=open(arquivo)
    with ler as f:
     for line in f:
       nome, sobrenome = line.split(":")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar um objeto com os atributos nome e sobrenome

```
class Objeto(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.nome = ''
        self.sobrenome = ''
```

depois disto você vai precisar trabalhar com arrays, a ideia é para cada linha dentro de seu forEach montar um objeto novo com os atributos preenchidos e adicioná-los a este array, com algumas alterações seu código ficaria assim:

```
arquivo=raw_input("Digite o nome do arquivo para separar: ")
    ler=open(arquivo)
    nomes = []
    with ler as f:
        for line in f:
            obj = Objeto()
            obj.nome, obj.sobrenome = line.split(":")
            nomes.append(obj)
```

Agora você tem todos os nomes dentro de seu array `nomes`

Para ter acesso aos item pode testar:

```
for item in nomes:
    print('nome: ' + item.nome + ' , Sobrenome: ' + item.sobrenome)
```

Você pode converter esta lista para `json`, para isto vai precisar criar o seguinte método (Objeto para dict):

```
def para_dict(obj):
    if hasattr(obj, '__dict__'):
        obj = obj.__dict__
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        return { k:para_dict(v) for k,v in obj.items() }
    elif isinstance(obj, list) or isinstance(obj, tuple):
        return [para_dict(e) for e in obj]
    else:
        return obj
```

Agora é possível fazer a conversão para `json`

```
import json
jsonstr = json.dumps(para_dict(nomes))
```

Comment: Valeu!, tava precisando

Comment: tenho uma outra duvida, estou tentando enviar os dados depois pro meu site com import requests, porem ele só está enviando o ultimo nome:sobrenome e os primeiros dão erro, será q o problema é nesse sistema de lista?

Comment: na verdade tem a ver com a serialização do objeto, basicamente você precisa mudar a serialização do objeto, a melhor maneira de enviar para outro sistema atraves de requests é envialos como json, vou editar a resposta

Comment: Resposta editada, vc vai precisar alterar a forma de construir seu objeto, criar o método que transforma o objeto para dict e ai sim consegue pegar o json, o json vc consegue enviar via request